# Segmentation fault в реализации класса Any

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, segmentation-fault

В процессе изучения C++ решал вот [эту задачу](https://stepik.org/lesson/564/step/11?unit=887). Если кратко, то экземпляры нешаблонного класса Any (который и нужно реализовать) должны иметь способность хранить значение любого типа, но об условии задания по ссылке, оно весьма объёмное.

Был написан следующий код (IClonable и ValueHolder здесь определены для полноты картины, в самом задании это не требуется, т.к. было реализовано раньше):

```
struct ICloneable
{
    virtual ICloneable* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~ICloneable() { }
};

template <typename T>
struct ValueHolder : public ICloneable
{
    T data_;

    ValueHolder(const T& obj) : data_(obj) {}

    ValueHolder* clone() const
    {
        return new ValueHolder(data_);
    }
};

class Any
{

    ICloneable* data_;

public:    

    Any(): data_(0) {};

    ~Any() { delete data_; }

    template <typename T>
    Any(T obj) : data_(new ValueHolder<T>(obj)) {};     

    Any(const Any& obj)
    {
        if (!obj.data_) data_ = 0;
        data_ = obj.data_->clone();
    }

    template <typename T>
    Any& operator=(const T & obj)
    {
        delete data_;
        data_ = new ValueHolder<T>(obj);
        return *this;
    }

    Any& operator=(const Any& obj)
    {
        if (this != &obj)
        {
            if (!obj.data_) data_ = 0;
            // if (!obj.data_) return; работающая версия
            delete data_;
            data_ = obj.data_->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T* cast()
    {
        if (!data_) return 0;
        ValueHolder<T>* cast_try = dynamic_cast< ValueHolder<T>* >(data_);
        if (!cast_try) return 0;
        return &(cast_try->data_);
    }
};
```

Тестирующая система по непонятным мне причинам указывала на ошибку сегментации. 
После многочисленных танцев с бубном в конструкторе копирования я поменял `if (!obj.data_) data_ = 0;` на `if (!obj.data_) return;` и все по не менее непонятным мне причинам заработало.

Но дальше самое интересное, в решениях пользователей я вижу вот такую реализацию:

```
#include <utility>

struct ICloneable;
template <typename T>
struct ValueHolder;

struct Any {
    Any() : data_(0) {}
    ~Any() { delete data_; }
    Any(const Any& other) : data_(other.data_ ? other.data_->clone() : 0) {}
    template <typename T> Any(const T& value) : data_(new ValueHolder<T>(value)) {}
    template <typename T> T* cast() 
    {
        ValueHolder<T>* castedValue;
        return data_ && (castedValue = dynamic_cast< ValueHolder<T>* >(data_)) ? &(castedValue->data_) : 0;
    }
    Any & operator=(const Any & other) 
    {
        if(this != &other) 
        {
            Any tmp(other);
            std::swap(data_, tmp.data_);
        }
        return *this;
    }
private:
    ICloneable* data_;
};
```

Можно заметить, что конструктор копирования и вообще большинство методов (кроме оператора присваивания) реализованы аналогично.
Вопросы: 1. Почему не работает первая версия кода? 2. Почему вдруг работает вторая? 3. В чем разница между первой версией моего кода и кодом, который я увидел в решении и почему эта разница позволяет этому коду работать?

Закрадываются подозрения, что из-за удаления data_ в операторе присваивания могла произойти какая-то некорректная операция + возможно дело в двух версиях оператора присваивания в моем коде против одной версии в коде чужом.

Но это только смутные догадки и, даже если они верны, я был бы рад получить ответ что именно происходит и как этого избежать в будущем. (то есть преимущества реализации оператора присваивания в чужом коде в данном конкретном случае я уже оценил, но хотелось бы полного понимания процесса)

Уже заранее большое спасибо, что дочитали и пытаетесь въехать в эту проблему!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первой версии у вас разыменовывание нулевого указателя когда `obj.data_` нулевой, а во второй нет.

```
if (!obj.data_) data_ = 0;
data_ = obj.data_->clone();
```

Если бы код был лучше отформатирован, то ошибка была бы более заметна:

```
if(!obj.data_)
{
   data_ = 0;
}
data_ = obj.data_->clone();
```

Вместо `data_ = 0;` следовало бы написать `data_ = nullptr;`, присвоение нулевого литерала указателям - это атавизм.

Ну и вообще-то стоило бы поотлаживать программу, а не гадать.

Comment: Вот черт! :) то есть мне стоило в условии добавить после `data_ = 0;` еще и `return;` (хоть это и нехорошо) и все бы заработало? P.S. спасибо за совет о nullptr. P.P.S. я отлаживал, но, видимо, еще очень неопытен в отладке, не знаю куда смотреть.

Comment: @ВладСивирин Да, хотя в добавлении return нет ничего плохого. Также можно было бы сделать ветку else.

Comment: Какая глупая ошибка! Спасибо большое за объяснения, думал, проблема находится куда глубже.